# Connectivity issues, message "Network unreachable"

Tags: 18.04, docker, connection

I'm facing a lot of connectivity issues on my fresh Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS server.
I have installed Docker and

when running

```
docker run hello-world
```

... the following error occurs :

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally docker: Error
> response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp
> 18.213.137.78:443: connect: network is unreachable.

Same "network is unreachable" error for

```
docker pull
```

and

```
docker login
```

This command :

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

returns :

> connect: Network is unreachable

However, to my surprise :

```
ping google.com
```

works fine!

Can anybody help me? I have no clue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had created a server with only an IPv6 network interface.

8.8.8.8 is an IPv4 address, so I couldn't connect to it from the IPv6 network interface. Same for the Docker server.

In order to get IPv4 access to/from my server, I will need to attach an IPv4 interface to it.